# HP Universal Driver on Windows 2008 Print Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, print-server

have anyone experiences with HP Universal Driver and using it at terminal server (Windows 2008 Server)?

I have LaserJet 2055 and on [HP Download page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3662052&prodNameId=3662058&swEnvOID=1060&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ja-45285-11) is only this driver. How can i install it into windows 2008 print server? Users who have connected this printer want to print on this printer via remote desktop. 
(Easy Print doesn't work, because they have Win2000...)

Thanks a lot

Comment: We use the HP LaserJet 4350 PS driver. Not sure if that will for your HP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I'll try to answer. You have few options:

**Preferrable and correct.**

Get/buy dedicated print server device, plug the printer into it, and connect it to the network, configure for specific static IP address. On desired Windows machine add a new printer, create new TCP/IP port with the IP of your printer server, and specify driver for the connected printer.

**Shared.**

Just connect the printer to particular machine, install drivers, get the printer to work & share it. Browse this machine from another one over network, find the printer, connect to it. You must think about permissions here.

Comment: no, i must only install drivers on Windows Server 2008, the printer is connected to user's computer. Users are connecting to windows via terminal services (remote desktop services). Normally, if they have installed WinXP and .NET fw 3, they can print on their printers without installing any drivers on server (Easy Print), but they have old OS, so i have to install drivers. Problem is, that on HP download site is only "HP Universal Driver" and although i install it, printing service doesn't recognize user's printer..

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a printer using the built-in HP LaserJet 4100 Series PCL6 driver.  We use this for almost all of our HP black and white printers.  You would also need to add the x86 driver if your 2008 server is x64. (Sharing tab > Additional Drivers).